# Controlling the appearance of custom button's predefined content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create a custom button template that has a predefined content: a vector image (Path) and text (TextBlock). Then I would like to define a style that, for example, would control the Path.Fill or TextBlock.Foreground based on different visual states.

What is the best approach to achieve this? Do I need to create a custom control that inherits from ButtonBase, and then expose dependency properties for Path and Text, or is there a better way?

Just to be clear, the idea is that later I can create multiple instances of this button, and just assign to it a Path and a Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `Style` for the `Button`, set the `ControlTemplate` in the style to use the Path and TextBlock. Define a couple of Attached Properties to modify Path and TextBlock visual state, if you have a need for something beyond what a button template could provide you.